# How to order index of duplicate records into another column by SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had below data

> - A
> - A
> - B
> - B
> - B
> - C

---

Now I want to order duplicate values into another column like this

---

> - A | 1
> - A | 2
> - B | 1
> - B | 2
> - B | 3
> - C | 1

---

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to insert the values to table or just output then? What are the types of columns in table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use row_number()

```
select columnA, 
       row_number() over(partition by ColumnA order by 1) as Dup_Count
from Mytable
```

Comment: Thanks,You save my time !